# css select xml value and print

Tags: css, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="tibu.css"?>

<THREADS>
<thread address="0011">
<sms msgBox="inbox" date="2012-10-30T06:49:36.529Z" locked="false" seen="true" read="true" serviceCenter="121212" address="0011" encoding="plain">aaaa</sms>
</thread>
<thread address="0123">
<sms msgBox="inbox" date="2012-10-30T06:49:36.529Z" locked="false" seen="true" read="true" serviceCenter="121212" address="0123" encoding="plain">Bugbug</sms>
</thread>
</THREADS>
```

Is it possible to select the `date` value and then print it?
If "yes" how can i do it?

Comment: i want to style the xml with css!

Comment: CSS cannot do this. You need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think CSS can do this, or if it can it isn't the best tool for the job

Take a look at XSL Transformations

XSLT is used to transform an XML document into another XML document, or another type of document that is recognized by a browser, like HTML and XHTML. Normally XSLT does this by transforming each XML element into an (X)HTML element.

Very good resource and tutorials

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/